# CSS - spring side menu on hover

Tags: html, css

I would like to implement a side menu described and implemented [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/sliding.en.html#a11n). I can achieve almost the same effect as demonstrated on the webpage, but when the menu retracts (the mouse leaves the menu surface), there is no transition. In other words, in my case the menu disappears, instead of retracting according to transition period.

My CSS code is provided below:

```css
.nav_menu {
   /*font*/
   font-family: inherit; /*inherited from <body>*/
   /*position*/
   float: left;
   /*dimension*/
   height: 100%;
   width: 20em;
   margin-top: 4em; 
   box-sizing: border-box;
   background-color: var(--nav_menu);
  
   position: relative;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
   .nav_menu {
      left: -16em;  
   }
   
   .nav_menu:hover {
      left: 0em;
      transition: 0.2s;
   }
}
```

Any recommendation on what I am doing wrong and why the same code works on the webpage ?

Comment: That’s because you only specified `transition` for the `:hover` state. You want to set it for the normal element state instead, so that it works in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your transition in your main div instead of hover

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
   .nav_menu {
      left: -16em;
      transition: 0.2s; 
   }

   .nav_menu:hover {
      left: 0em;

   }
}
```